# Pandas dataframe and appending objects in conversion to JSON

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, if-statement

Basically I´m reading a xlsx file using pandas and converting it to json file. I idk how to do it, but I think I have to create a 'if' statement to read each row and find which elements are different regarding to the previous line and then append it in my object.

**Data that I´m reading** :

```
id     label        id_customer     label_customer    part_number 

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          7897

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-99992         Brazil          982

6     Sao Paulo      CUST-43535         Brazil          435

92    Hong Hong      CUST-88888         China           785
```

================================

**Here is my code:**

```
import pandas as pd
import json

file_imported = pd.read_excel('testing.xlsx', sheet_name = 'Plan1')

list_final  = []
for index, row in file_imported.iterrows():
    list1 = []
    list_final.append ({
        "id"       : int(row['id']),
        "label"    : str(row['label']),
        "Customer" : list1
        })

    list2 = []
    list1.append ({
       "id"       : str(row['id_customer']) ,
       "label"    : str(row['label_customer']),
       "number"   :  list2
       })

    list2.append({
        "part"    : str(row['part_number'])  
       })      

print (list_final)

with open ('testing.json', 'w') as f:
    json.dump(list_final, f, indent= True)
```

================================

**Json output:**

```
    [
     {
      "id": 6,
      "label": "Sao Paulo",
      "Customer": [
       {
        "id": "CUST-99992",
        "label": "Brazil",
        "number" : [
        {
        "part": "7897"
        }
        ]
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "id": 6,
      "label": "Sao Paulo",
      "Customer": [
       {
        "id": "CUST-99992",
        "label": "Brazil",
        "number" : [
        {
        "part": "982"
        }
        ]
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "id": 6,
      "label": "Sao Paulo",
      "Customer": [
       {
        "id": "CUST-43535",
        "label": "Brazil",
        "number" : [
        {
        "part": "435"
        }
        ]
       }
      ]
     },
     {
      "id": 92,
      "label": "Hong Hong",
      "Customer": [
       {
        "id": "CUST-88888",
        "label": "China",
        "number" : [
        {
        "part": "785"
        }
        ]
       }
      ]
     }
    ]
```

================================

**and I need something like this:**

```
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "7897"
    },
    {
    "part": "982"
    }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-43535",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "435"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Hong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China",
    "number" : [
    {
    "part": "785"
    }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

=====================

Can somebody help me?????

Comment: Don’t use `.iterrows()`. I strongly suggest familiarizing yourself with Pandas a bit more, before attempting to write any complex programs.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looking at your desired json, it is structured into two groups.  The first contains the `id` and `label` fields, and the second contains the `id_customer` and `label_customer` fields.  The inner most data is the`part_number`, which can be created using a list comprehension together with a dictionary comprehension: `[{'part': str(p)} for p in df2['part_number']]`.  The rest is just data munging.

```
import json

result = []
for labels, df1 in df.groupby(['id', 'label']):
    id_, label = labels
    record = {'id': int(id_), 'label': label, 'Customer': []}
    for inner_labels, df2 in df1.groupby(['id_customer', 'label_customer']):
        id_, label = inner_labels
        record['Customer'].append({
            'id': id_, 
            'label': label, 
            'number': [{'part': str(p)} for p in df2['part_number']]
        })
    result.append(record)
>>> print(json.dumps(result, indent=True))
[
 {
  "id": 6,
  "label": "Sao Paulo",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-43535",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number": [
     {
      "part": "435"
     }
    ]
   },
   {
    "id": "CUST-99992",
    "label": "Brazil",
    "number": [
     {
      "part": "7897"
     },
     {
      "part": "982"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 },
 {
  "id": 92,
  "label": "Hong Kong",
  "Customer": [
   {
    "id": "CUST-88888",
    "label": "China",
    "number": [
     {
      "part": "785"
     }
    ]
   }
  ]
 }
]
```

Comment: Thanks a lot for your help @Alexander.. your comment is very useful, but  `"id": "CUST-99992"` first than `"id": "CUST-43535"` (like my dataframe order), what could I modify in my code?

Comment: Another question, my dataframe has 38 columns, and actually `number` is another list with `part_number` and `serial_number` keys, Should I create a row like `for inner_labels, df3 in df2.groupby(['part_number', 'serial_number']):` below `id_, label = inner_labels`??

Comment: To keep the original order, add `sort=False` to the two `groupby` statements.  Note that you are grouping, so if the same customer was in multiple locations, the records would be grouped together. `'number': [{'part': str(p), 'serial': str(s)} for p, s in zip(df2['part_number'], df2['serial_number']]`

Comment: Like it @Alexander !! Following the same path, just bellow '`serial:`' in `'number'` list, I have another list '`client`' with `'client_number' and 'client_order'` and just below `'client_order'` I started another list with other keys.. how can I implement these lists?